# Getting wordpress post ID in functions.php

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms

I'm using a JQuery form in Wordpress which when submitted calls a function from the functions.php file. I need to be able to access the post id in that function (test_function).

(1) HTML code in my page's php. This is the form that calls the 'test_function'.

```
<form autocomplete="off" id="form-id" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php')?>" method="post">
<input type="text" name="coords" placeholder="Coordinates" value="Some Value"/><br>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="test_function"/>
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
</form>
```

(2) external JS file enqueued in my functions.php

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#form-id').ajaxForm({
  success: function(response){
    console.log(response);
  },
  error: function(response){
    console.log(response);
  },
  resetForm:true
});
});
```

(3) test_function in functions.php

```
function test_function(){
    //do something here that needs the POST ID
}

add_action('wp_ajax_test_function', 'test_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_test_function', 'test_function');
```

I'm not sure how to approach this.
I've tried all 3 methods below but none work.

```
global $post; $post_id = $post->ID;

global $wp_query; $post_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();

$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ] . $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ];
$current_post_id = url_to_postid( $url );
```

Comment: Multiple post id having you want which post?

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_ajax_posts() {
    // Query Arguments
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => array('post'),
        'post_status' => array('publish'),
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'order' => 'DESC'
    );

    // The Query
    $ajaxposts = get_posts( $args ); // changed to get_posts from wp_query, because `get_posts` returns an array

    echo json_encode( $ajaxposts );

    exit; // exit ajax call(or it will return useless information to the response)
}

// Fire AJAX action for both logged in and non-logged in users
add_action('wp_ajax_get_ajax_posts', 'get_ajax_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_ajax_posts', 'get_ajax_posts');
```

Comment: i'm not sure how this is relevant to get the current post's id

Comment: You want current post I’d pass to via ajax